# One selenium test (using testng) executes AfterSuite method, another test case does not

Tags: selenium, testng

I have come across a situation where one Selenium test does execute `@AfterSuite` block, while the other does not.

I am running both the test using `testng.xml`.

Initially I thought there might be some config issue in `testng.xml`; but I closed down the issue to test case level and my intuition says there is something which I am missing in test case level.

My `@AfterSuite` block is actually responsible for sending email after the test execution is over, so it is part of a different package in my project; and not in Test Case level.

Here is the test case which does execute the `@AfterSuite` :

```
package unitTest;
/*import statements*/

public class OpenBrowser extends ExtentReport {

    @Test
    public void launch() throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        test = extent.createTest(Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[1].getMethodName());
        Base.getBrowser();
        System.out.println(ReadExcelData.readExcelData("Login.xlsx", 0, 0, 0));
        Login.LoginField(Base.driver).sendKeys(ReadExcelData.readExcelData("Login.xlsx", 0, 1, 0));
        Login.PasswordField(Base.driver).sendKeys(ReadExcelData.readExcelData("Login.xlsx", 0, 1, 1));
        Login.SignIn(Base.driver).click();

    }

    @AfterTest

    public void tearDown()

    {
        Base.closeBrowser();
    }

}
```

And the Test which does not execute the `@AfterSuite` block:

```
    package fundSearch;

    /* Import Statements*/
    public class FundNavigation extends ExtentReport {

        @Test
        public void verifyFundPage() {
            test = extent.createTest(Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[1].getMethodName());
            Base.getBrowser();
            Funds.FundsLink(Base.driver).click();
            Assert.assertEquals(Funds.SearchFundsField(Base.driver).isDisplayed(), true);
        }

        @AfterTest

        public void tearDown()

        {
            Base.closeBrowser();
        }

    }
```

The `ExtentReport.java` is below:

```
package com....core;
/*Import Statements*/

public class ExtentReport {
    public static ExtentHtmlReporter htmlReporter;
    public static ExtentReports extent;
    public static ExtentTest test;
    public static String suiteName;

    @BeforeSuite
    public static void setUp(ITestContext ctx) {

        // String currentDate=getDateTime();
        suiteName = ctx.getCurrentXmlTest().getSuite().getName();
        htmlReporter = new ExtentHtmlReporter(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/Reports/" + suiteName + ".html");
        extent = new ExtentReports();
        extent.attachReporter(htmlReporter);

        extent.setSystemInfo("OS", "Windows");
        extent.setSystemInfo("Host Name", "CI");
        extent.setSystemInfo("Environment", "QA");
        extent.setSystemInfo("User Name", "QA_User");

        htmlReporter.config().setChartVisibilityOnOpen(true);
        htmlReporter.config().setDocumentTitle("AutomationTesting Report");
        htmlReporter.config().setReportName("testReport");
        htmlReporter.config().setTestViewChartLocation(ChartLocation.TOP);
        htmlReporter.config().setTheme(Theme.STANDARD);
    }

    @AfterMethod
    public void getResult(ITestResult result) throws IOException {
        if (result.getStatus() == ITestResult.FAILURE) {
            String screenShotPath = GetScreenShot.capture(Base.driver, "screenShotName", result);
            test.log(Status.FAIL, MarkupHelper.createLabel(result.getName() + " Test case FAILED due to below issues:",
                    ExtentColor.RED));
            test.fail(result.getThrowable());
            test.fail("Snapshot below: " + test.addScreenCaptureFromPath(screenShotPath));
        } else if (result.getStatus() == ITestResult.SUCCESS) {
            test.log(Status.PASS, MarkupHelper.createLabel(result.getName() + " Test Case PASSED", ExtentColor.GREEN));
        } else {
            test.log(Status.SKIP,
                    MarkupHelper.createLabel(result.getName() + " Test Case SKIPPED", ExtentColor.ORANGE));
            test.skip(result.getThrowable());
        }
        extent.flush();
    }

    @AfterSuite
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("In After Suite");
        SendEmail.execute(SendEmail.path);
    }

    public static String getDateTime() {

        // Create object of SimpleDateFormat class and decide the format
        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");

        // get current date time with Date()
        Date date = new Date();

        // Now format the date
        String currentDate = dateFormat.format(date);

        String newDate = currentDate.replace('/', '_');
        String newCurrentDate = newDate.replace(':', '.');
        return newCurrentDate;

    }
}
```

The SendEmail.java is provided below:

```
/*Package Statement and Import Statements*/

public class SendEmail {

public static String path=System.getProperty("user.dir")+"/Reports/"+ExtentReport.suiteName+".html";

static String[] to={"xxx"};
static String[] cc={};
static String[] bcc={};

public static void execute(String reportFileName) throws Exception {


    SendEmail.sendMail("xxx@gmail.com",
            "xxx",
            "smtp.gmail.com",
            "465",
            "true",
            "true",
            true,
            "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory",
            "false",
            to,
            cc,
            bcc,
            "Automation report",
            System.getProperty("user.dir")+"/Reports/"+ExtentReport.suiteName+".html",
            path,
            reportFileName);

}

public static boolean sendMail(String userName,
        String passWord,
        String host,
        String port,
        String starttls,
        String auth,
        boolean debug,
        String socketFactoryClass,
        String fallback,
        String[] to,
        String[] cc,
        String[] bcc,
        String subject,
        String text,
        String attachmentPath,
        String attachmentName){

    //Object Instantiation of a properties file.
    Properties props = new Properties();

    props.put("mail.smtp.user", userName);

    props.put("mail.smtp.host", host);

    if(!"".equals(port)){
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", port);
    }

    if(!"".equals(starttls)){
        props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable",starttls);
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", auth);
    }

    if(debug){

        props.put("mail.smtp.debug", "true");

    }else{

        props.put("mail.smtp.debug", "false");

    }

    if(!"".equals(port)){
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", port);
    }
    if(!"".equals(socketFactoryClass)){
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class",socketFactoryClass);
    }
    if(!"".equals(fallback)){
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", fallback);
    }

    try{

        Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);

        session.setDebug(debug);

        MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session);

        msg.setText(text);

        msg.setSubject(subject);

        Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();
        MimeBodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
        DataSource source = new FileDataSource(attachmentPath);
        messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
        messageBodyPart.setFileName(attachmentName);
        multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

        msg.setContent(multipart);
        msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(userName));

        for(int i=0;i<to.length;i++){
            msg.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new
                    InternetAddress(to[i]));
        }

        for(int i=0;i<cc.length;i++){
            msg.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.CC, new
                    InternetAddress(cc[i]));
        }

        for(int i=0;i<bcc.length;i++){
            msg.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.BCC, new
                    InternetAddress(bcc[i]));
        }

        msg.saveChanges();

        Transport transport = session.getTransport("smtp");

        transport.connect(host, userName, passWord);

        transport.sendMessage(msg, msg.getAllRecipients());

        transport.close();

        return true;

    } catch (Exception mex){
        mex.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
}
```

}

My `testng.xml` is defined as below (for the first test):

```
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >
<suite name="DefaultSuite"  >
    <!-- <listeners>
      <listener class-name="org.uncommons.reportng.HTMLReporter"/>
      <listener class-name="org.uncommons.reportng.JUnitXMLReporter"/>
   </listeners>-->

    <test name="Test" >
    <classes>
       <class name="unitTest.OpenBrowser" />
     </classes>
    </test>


</suite>
```

The `testng.xml` for the second test is like below.

```
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >
<suite name="DefaultSuite"  >
    <!-- <listeners>
      <listener class-name="org.uncommons.reportng.HTMLReporter"/>
      <listener class-name="org.uncommons.reportng.JUnitXMLReporter"/>
   </listeners>-->

    <test name="Test" >
    <classes>
       <class name="fundSearch.FundNavigation" />
     </classes>
    </test>


</suite>
```

Could any one please point out if I am doing something wrong/difference for which `@Aftersuite` is running when the first test is executed and not when the second test is run?

Comment: Is the second test throwing any exception? Try by adding the option alwaysRun=true to the AfterSuite method

Comment: Hi Grasshopper.. Apparently, throwing an exception in the second test did not solve it. Also, even after setting up alwaysRun=true on @AfterSuite, it did not get executed.

Comment: This is due to your suite name. You have same suite name DefaultSuite  in both XML file. When you run second test it overwrites the first one. So will get only one report. Change suite name in one of XML file and try again. Please let me know.

Comment: Murthi... I am running both the tests separately, so there is no question of overwriting.

Comment: May be you are getting mail with same name. Are you getting mail after second test?

Comment: Murthi... No email after the second test... And sorry I did not get your point of email with same name....

Comment: 1. Put in the log of your second test wherein the aftersuite doesn't run. 2. Does beforesuite execute?

Comment: Niharika_Neo... 1. Where exactly do you want me to put the log? As you see, I have a print statement inside aftersuite, which does and does not show up, for the first and second test, respectively. 2. Yes, beforesuite runs sucessfully in both the cases.

Comment: @PrabodhGhosh - Can you please help call out how you are executing your tests ? In your question you have shared two different xmls. So its not clear as to which one you are running.

Comment: @krishnan I am running the tests one by one, using the applicable suite. It is not something i am trying to run both of them together.

Comment: @PrabodhGhosh - So if I understand your issue correctly, you are saying that when you execute testng_1.xml (your 1st suite), the AfterSuite gets executed, but when you execute testng_2.xml (your 2nd suite) the AfterSuite does not get executed ? Is that a proper understanding of your problem statement ?

Comment: @KrishnanMahadevan You are right

Comment: @PrabodhGhosh -In that case, please bump the verbosity to "3" (i.e., set `verbose=3` in your suite xml file wherein you are noticing that your `@AfterSuite` is not running) and share the output. TestNG should print to you the set of methods that were to be invoked. That should add some clarity to what got and what did not get called.

Comment: When I run the testng.xml for which aftersuite gets executed, I get the below in the console:

Comment: I am not able to paste the output here because of space constraint. Is there any way I can get your email id so that I can share the output? My email is suhanapiku@gmail.com